# C program with system() or popen() compiled in msys64 not really working in Win10 cmd shell

Tags: c, mingw-w64

I wrote a GTK program in C on my GNU/Linux machine using the popen() call. Now I need to port it to Windows10.

I can compile it and it's running when started from the mingw64 terminal.

However if I start it from a regular Win10 cmd shell it only works if the executable is in the installation directory.

I have identified that the problem is the popen() call (and system()), however, I can't fnd a solution.

I have a simple example:

systest.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fp;

    system( "pwd" );
}
```

I copied msys-2.0.dl into the same directory as systest.exe. Launched from a cmd shell it prints the working directory. However if I put the two files in another directory, system() just fails and does nothing.

I am really stuck and I'd appreciate hints to bring me further.

Thank you,
Flo

**Update**

Thank you for your comments, I am updating systest.c and simplifying the command to be executed:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fp;

    printf("+++ system NULL: %d\n", system( NULL ));
    printf("+++ system echo: %d\n", system( "echo hello" ));
}
```

If I execute it in a cmd shell in my mingw64 home directory the output is

```
+++ system NULL: 1
hello
+++ system echo: 0
```

If I create bin as a subdirectory and copy systest.exe and msys-2.0.dll into it and execute systest there (again in a cmd shell) I get the following output:

```
+++ system NULL: 1
+++ system echo: 127
```

Why is that? The mechanismn behind it is not clear to me.

Btw: The compilation took place in a mingw64 shell: gcc -o systest systest.c

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: how do you know system fails?

Comment: is 'pwd' in the window's Path?

Comment: pwd is a  powershell command not a cmd command

Comment: What is the return value from `system(…)`?

Comment: there's no `pwd` in Windows unless you have cygwin or msys in path. And you shouldn't spawn a whole new process just to get the current directory. Just call [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory)

Comment: Right, there is no pwd at the cmd shell. However when compiled in the msys environment and equiped with msys-2.0.dll I am operating again in the msys environment though I am executing the program within a cmd shell.
Therefore 'pwd' did work and the ouput was '/home/flo' which is the notation of the mingw64 shell. Copying into bin subdirectory made it fail.

Comment: in POSIX use [getcwd](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html). There's still absolutely no reason to run pwd

Comment: I don't need to run pwd, this was just an example. Replaced now by a simpler one.